# c# sql query problems

Tags: c#, sql

This is OCR. My system allow the users to input an image which consist of a character, fill in the particular character and the description. The input data will be inserted into the database. Here's my question, if the user want to input an image with the same character but in different font, they do not need to retype the character and also the description. they may just need to use the import button which can import the existing image to let the system know both characters are the same. So, when user input image for the system to scan, the system may know the character which is in different font.

Then how I code the system to inform the system that the character is the same when user import existing?

## region Library Training(Tab2_Component)

```
    private void Browse1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //open file dialog for the users to input image to the system
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            //Set default directory to the open file dialog
            open.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop";

            //limit input image type for the users
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg)|*.jpg; *.jpeg";

            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                singleFileInfo = new FileInfo(open.FileName);
                string dirName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(open.FileName);
                imgLoc.Text = open.FileName;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed loading image");
        }
    }

    private void typeRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set the textbox to editable and the "import" button unclickable when user select the "Type Character" radio button
        CharTB.ReadOnly = false;
        ImportButton.Enabled = false;
        DescTB.ReadOnly = false;
    }

    private void importRadio_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set the "import" button to clickable and the textbox to uneditable when the user select "Import Existing" radio button
        ImportButton.Enabled = true;
        CharTB.ReadOnly = true;
        DescTB.ReadOnly = true;
    }

    private void AddBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SHEN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CharacterImage;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        //set variables to the textbox.text
        String ImageLocation = imgLoc.Text;
        String typeName = CharTB.Text;
        String ImportExt = importTB.Text;
        String CharDesc = DescTB.Text;
        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ImageLocation);
        String savePath = @"C:\Users\Shen\Desktop\LenzOCR\LenzOCR\WindowsFormsApplication1\ImageFile\" + fileName;

        inputImageBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ImageLocation);
        inputImageBox.Image.Save(savePath);

        String insertData = "INSERT INTO CharacterImage(ImageName, ImagePath, Character, CharacterDescription) VALUES('"+fileName+"', '"+savePath+"', '"+typeName+"', '"+CharDesc+"')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Character Inserted", "Insert Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        descDisplayTB.Text = typeName + "\r\n\r\n" + CharDesc;
        //set the Textbox to empty and the "Type Character" textboxt to uneditable 
        //and the "Import" button to unclickable after user add the data into the database
        imgLoc.Text = "";
        CharTB.Text = "";
        importTB.Text = "";
        DescTB.Text = "";
        CharTB.ReadOnly = true;
        ImportButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        descDisplayTB.Text = "";
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misunderstood your question but it seems you would need a multi table database to do it

An example

1. Users + font details (I didnt understand what font detail)
2. Upload details, eg scanned item

In terms of database it maybe more useful to do

1. users
2. image details
3. link between user_id and image_id

Instead of resetting the description and character etc, what you could do is ask if they want to insert another based on the same image.

I didnt truly understand the font part of this.

Comment: what i mean is, user input image, character and description. Then if the user wan to input another image with same character and decsription, the user only need to import existing one to tell the system that the character and description is the same so that they do not need to reenter the character and description again.